# Getting "Record does not exist or has been deleted " error when trying to add service product in sales order line via APIs

Tags: python, odoo

I am using Odoos APIs as per the documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html

When trying to add a service product into a sales order line, I'm getting the error:

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 2: "('Record does not exist or has been deleted.\\n(Record: product.product(14589,), User: 2)', None)">
```

This is only happening when I'm trying to add a newly created service product. But when adding old service products that already existed before we migrated to Odoo 13, it works fine.

I'm adding the service product order line as follows:

```
order_line_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order.line', 'create', [{
'order_id':sales_order_id
,'product_id':odoo_product_id
,'name': product_sku
,'price_unit':product_price
,'product_uom_qty':product_quantity
,'state':'sale'
,'qty_delivered_method': 'manual'
,'customer_lead': 0.0
,'invoice_status':'no'
,'product_type': 'service'
}])
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: The error means that the `odoo_product_id` you are giving doesn't exist in the database. A common mistake is searching the `product.template` instead of `product.product`. Can you show  how `odoo_product_id` has been assigned?

Comment: @ObayAbd-Algader You are right once i changed it to product.product it worked. Many Thanks :) . Do you know why this happens ?

Comment: There is two objects for product in Odoo, the first is `product.template` which is what you see when you open Inventory > Master Data > Products, and the other is `product.product` which is the variant(s) of that product. Also `product.product` is the one that is tracked in stock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using `product.product` instead of `product.template`, that is a common mistake.